# display pointer position of file

Tags: c, file-io

hi every kindly tell me how to display pointer position
for eg

fpos_t pos;

(fgetpos(fp, &pos) 
how to disply pos value

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this portably you're not supposed to try and display that pos value.
Try using ftell() instead.

```
long pos;
pos = ftell(fp);
printf("pos is %ld bytes\n", pos);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't. An fpos_t contains more than the offset: it has information to reset correctly the handling of character sets having a shift state. ftell() gives you an offset (but pay attention, its range can be limited to less that the possible file size).

Answer (score 0):

In some Unix systems `fpos_t` is equivalent to `off_t` or `long int`, but in other systems, it might have a different internal representation.

```
pos_t position;
fgetpos(stream, &position);
...
fsetpos(stream, &position);
printf("offset: %ld\n", position.__pos);
                ^^^              ^^^^^
```

With a `long` integer data type it works fine, but I repeat that the internal representation of `fpos_t` varies from system to system.